# How to open angular modal on focus reactive form text field?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap

I need to open angular `(Ngbmodal)` modal when focus on a read-only text field. But when I do, it opens the modal but shows an error in the console and unable to close the modal.

Error:

[image]

Text Field :

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="true" placeholder="Please select a user" (focus)="openUserSelectModal()" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
```

Modal open function:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.basicAccountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

}

```
openUserSelectModal() {
const modal = this.modalService.open(UserSelectorComponent, { size: 'sm', container: 'nb-layout' });

modal.result.then((username) => {
  if (username) {
    this.basicAccountForm.controls['username'].setValue(username);
  }
}, () => {
  this.basicAccountForm.controls['username'].setValue(null);
});
 }
```

[Stackblitz Editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwrywq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this use event.PreventDefault
**Html**

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="true" placeholder="Please select a user" (focus)="openModal($event)" formControlName="username" class="form-control"/>
```

**TS**

```
 openModal(event) {
    event.srcElement.blur();
  event.preventDefault();
    const userModal = this.modalService.open(UserComponent, { size: 'sm' });
  }
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4md9fd

Comment: Yeah, I added this on parent component where calls modal open. But didn't work.

Comment: try this ngAfterViewChecked(){
   //your code to update the model
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
}

Comment: Thanks, But didn't work. I think I am doing something wrong. Here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwrywq for you.

Comment: @Randika check now